# Set Visual Studio's 'Debug Source Files' paths programmatically

Tags: visual-studio

I can set where VS searches source files manually:
[Debug Source Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B360.png)

Is there a way to set these paths programmatically?

Thanks